# JPA/Hibernate remove all in Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have this Entity Class

```
public class Entity {

    @Id 
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="flusso", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<Cron> listCron;

    //getter and setter Method
}
```

and in my Dao Class i have this method

```
(...)
    @Transactional
    public void removeAll(Entity entity) throws PersistenceDaoException {
        try {
            final Class<? extends Object> paramClass = entity.getClass();
            String nameClass = paramClass.getSimpleName();
            Query q = em.createQuery ("DELETE FROM " + nameClass);
            int del = q.executeUpdate ();
            if (del == 1){
                System.out.println("risultato:" + del);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
(...)
```

I do a simple test and i have this problem:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:310)
    at $Proxy24.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at it.synclab.fb.jpa.dao.impl.GenericDaoImpl.removeAll(GenericDaoImpl.java:138)
    at it.synclab.fb.jpa.dao.impl.FlussoDaoImpl.removeAll(FlussoDaoImpl.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
    at $Proxy22.removeAll(Unknown Source)
    at it.synclab.fb.jpa.test.FlussoDaoTest.main(FlussoDaoTest.java:30)
```

This method is marked with @Transactional, where am I doing wrong?

PS:This is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="fb-persistence" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"> 
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/> 
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


    <bean name="entityDaoImpl" class="it.synclab.fb.jpa.dao.impl.EntityDaoImpl" />
```

Comment: Judging from your stacktrace it looks like your using the Springframework.  Can you provide your spring context xml?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a transaction manager in your context.

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html (9.5.6)

Comment: I have add my context and as you can see i have a transaction manager ("transactionManager")